# Protobuf message itself is a map vs. message has an element that is a map

Tags: protocol-buffers

When defining a `proto` file, how can one specify if the whole message is a `map<string, uint64>` or if it contains an element that is a `map<string, uint64>`. So for example, how do you write a `proto` for

```
{
    "abc": 1243,
    "def": 2343
}
```

Where the keys are arbitrary and you don't know them beforehand, vs.

```
{
    "foo": {
        "abc": 1243,
        "def": 2343
    }
}
```

I assume the latter would be:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Result {
    map<string, uint64> foo = 1;
}
```

But how do you define the first then?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the binary format or the json format? the reason I ask is that as far as the binary format is concerned, the latter **is** just "repeated {map entry}" - that is the *only* thing that will appear on the wire (the root object kinda doesn't exist as a separate entity in the binary format). So... your final proto example does exactly what you want, from the perspective of the binary output. From the perspective of the json output, it might simply not be possible to get what you want. Protobuf *is not* a general purpose JSON library; it is an opinionated serialization library that happens to have  JSON as one of the outputs - but the "opinionated" is the key phrase: it means that you might not be able to do some specific things. If you want to write *very particular* JSON layouts, you should be using a general purpose JSON library, not protobuf.

Comment: Well, it's about the schema definition and usage in Go. If my result is a `type Response map[string]uint64` how would the `proto` file look like? Currently, that doesn't appear to work so I would need a `type Response struct` with the `map[string]uint64` as structure element. Same applies to arrays BTW. Seems that the Protobuf message itself can only be a struct, right? I cannot represent a flat array, I can only represent a structure with one element holding an array.

Comment: @smares k... by "struct", do you mean `message`? or do you mean `google.protobuf.Struct`, which is a very specific message that contains a `map<string,google.protobuf.Value>`? and *in what context* is this? is this RPC? serialization? or what? *Usually*, most APIs will expect to be talking about a `message` (maybe via a descriptor), which would be your `Result` type here. Note that `google.protobuf.Struct` still wouldn't be able to represent *quite* your data, unless the API wraps it - it is really `{ "abc": { "number_value ": 1243 }, "def": { "number_value ": 2343} }` - at least conceptually

Comment: but *if* your specific library encapsulates the above automagically, then sure: just use a `google.protobuf.Struct` (per https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was referring to a Golang struct (like a C++ struct).

Comment: And it's a REST API, I am talking about the responses it sends. So for a call to `GET http://api.whatever/friends/`, the response I want to send is an array of friends. Using Protobuf, it appears that the response would not be a flat `[{friend}, {friend}, {friend}]` but `{"friends": [{friend}, {friend}, {friend}]}`.